# Folder permission loophole with Nextcloud installation

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, nextcloud, snap

I have installed Nextcloud via snap on a Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon system.
Since I wanted Nextcloud to use a dedicated HD for its data, I have mounted an HD to `/mnt/nextcloud` and made a `/data` folder into it as explained here https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/wiki/Change-data-directory-to-use-another-disk-partition

The installation seems to work at first, I can go to `localhost` and set up username and password. After that though, I get the following error:

> Your data directory is invalid
>
> Ensure there is a file called ".ocdata" in the root of the data directory.
>
> Your data directory is not writable
>
> Permissions can usually be fixed by giving the webserver write access to the root directory. See https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/21/go.php?to=admin-dir_permissions.

The file `.ocdata` is actually in the directory, so it must be a permission problem. But if I change the folder permission from `0770` to `777` I get:

> Your data directory is readable by other users
>
> Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.
>
> If I change it back to `0770`, I get the first error.
> The link https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/21/go.php?to=admin-dir_permissions doesn't point to any solution either.

I have also tried `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /mnt/nextcloud/data`, but I still get the first error.

Any idea on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snap runs as confined root. Try `sudo chown -R root:root /mnt/nextcloud/data`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can't set the permissions right, another option is to disable the "data directory permissions" check by adding this in the config.php

```
'check_data_directory_permissions' => false
```

Then you'll not get the "Your data directory is readable by other users" error anymore.